# Kartik export widget not export search result Yii2

Tags: widget, export, yii2

Fighting form last 3 days not able to find what exactly problem is. When after search I export data it export all data, expected to export search result.Please help!

My Controller

```
 public function actionAdvancesearch()
 {
    $searchModel = new CandidateSearch();
    $model = new Candidate();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
            $postedData=Yii::$app->request->post();
            $searchModel = new CandidateSearch();
            $dataProvider1 = $searchModel->searchAdvanced();
            return $this->render('candidateAdvSearch', ['dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
             'model' => $model ,
              'searchModel' => $searchModel, 
              'posted'=>"posted",
              'postedData'=>$postedData]);
    }else{
        return $this->render('candidateAdvSearch', ['searchModel' => $searchModel, 'model' => $model, 'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1]);
    }

 }
```

View

```
Pjax::begin();
if($dataProvider1){
$gridColumns = [
        [
         'attribute'=>'HRMS_candidateID',
            'label'=>'Candidate ID',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'width'=>'190px',
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { 
                return $model->HRMS_candidateID;
            },
            'format'=>'raw'
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'HRMS_candidateFirstName',
            'label'=>'Candidate FirstName',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'width'=>'190px',
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { 
                return $model->HRMS_candidateFirstName;
            },
            'format'=>'raw'
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'HRMS_candidateLastName',
            'label'=>'Candidate LastName',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'width'=>'190px',
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return $model->HRMS_candidateLastName;            },
            'format'=>'raw'
        ],  
    ];

    $fullExportMenu = ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'target' => ExportMenu::TARGET_POPUP,
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'pjaxContainerId' => 'kv-pjax-container',
            'dropdownOptions' => [
                'label' => 'Full',
                'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                'itemsBefore' => [
                    '<li class="dropdown-header">Export All Data</li>',
            ],
        ],
    ]);


    // Generate a bootstrap responsive striped table with row highlighted on hover
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'pjax' => true,
            'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container']],
            'panel' => [
                'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i> Candidate Advanced Search</h3>',
            ],          
        'toolbar' => [
                 $fullExportMenu,
            ],

        'striped'=>true,
        'hover'=>true,
        'responsive'=>true,
        'hover'=>true,
        'resizableColumns'=>true,
        'persistResize'=>false,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,  
    ]); 
}
 Pjax::end();
```

Comment: Does the search work?

Comment: Yes it gives expected output.